# A medieval book with a redhead girl as a main character who allies with vampires and werewolves against scientific opposition

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for a book about a girl who fights a war after her father dies. She forms an alliance with vampires and werewolves and other creatures. The opposition believes in science. She wins the war.

Comment: Congrats on getting your answer. And welcome to the site!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could this be *[The Cry of the Icemark](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/248309.The_Cry_of_the_Icemark)*?

[image: Book cover for *The Cry of the Icemark*]

> The Icemark is a kingdom in grave danger. Its king has been killed in battle, its enemy lies in wait, and its fate rests on the shoulders of one girl. Thirrin Freer Strong-in-the-Arm Lindenshield, a beautiful princess and an intrepid warrior, must find a way to protect her land from a terrible invasion. She will forge an extraordinary alliance of noble Snow Leopards, ancient Vampires, and ferocious Wolf-folk. She will find unexpected strength in her friendship with a young warlock. And she will lead her allies to victory with her fierce battle cry: "Blood! Blast! And Fire!"

From [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cry_of_the_Icemark#Plot), note of the empire being science-based:

> Thirrin, having just made an alliance with the werewolves by saving their king, must now seek out more allies, as the Icemark and the werewolves alone cannot defeat the Empire. Although they have the support of their vassal, the Hypolitan, more are needed. Thirrin, with the aid of a young warlock, Oskan Witch's Son, must attempt to win over the Vampire King and Queen. They know this will be difficult because of the centuries of distrust and hatred between the two races. Because the Empire hates all that is unscientific and irrational, the Vampires know that if the Icemark falls, the Empire will wipe out the Vampires next. With this in mind, the Vampires reluctantly agree to send aid.

Found by searching for *medieval fantasy novel redheaded girl allies with vampires and werewolves against science*

Comment: Interesting. I'd never heard of it before. And frankly, it seems to me that if someone said, "You can root for the side with all the blood-sucking vampires, or you can root for the side that believes in science and technology," I'd probably throw in my lot with the Empire.

Comment: @Lorendiac: I suppose it all depends on what the sides do with their gifts. I get the impression from the summaries that the Empire is a tad genocidal, with heavy parallels to the Romans trying to eradicate the barbarians.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots As long as you paid taxes and didn't cause troubles, the Romans would leave you alone, so I'd take the Romans over the barbarians any time of day...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I agree with Rebel-Scum that the Romans weren't trying to exterminate their neighbors. Just conquer them when they thought they could make it work. But if this fictional Empire told me it saw vampires and werewolves as serious threats to the "public health" of everyone else, and wanted to exterminate them, I might be persuaded to cheer them on!